# cakephp what this line do

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cake php and need to know how to trace and what this line of code does.
thanks

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('TABLE1.0.nextpage',array('value'=>'/page8'));
```

Answer (score 4):

That line outputs a hidden input field with the value of 'page8'.

It should produce something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='/page8' name='TABLE1.0.nextpage' id='TABLE1.0.nextpage' />
```

Comment: is that pretty common way to use the hidden fields in cakephp

Comment: Yep! You can also do this: $form->input('name/id', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=> $somevalue));         It's always good to take advantage of these mechanisms that cake provides for generating HTML, when possible.